# .net 2.0 application in 64 bit processor?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, 64-bit

We are going to write a C# 2.0 (VS2005) application targetting 64-bit server.

I found this link by ms http://support.microsoft.com/kb/912891#appliesto

"When you run a 64-bit application that was built by using the .NET Framework, you may notice that the application uses more memory than a similar 32-bit application"

I just want to know is this being resolved ?? or there is new SP to be used ??

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 4):

This is to be expected. Pointers are bigger in x64 than in x32. It's the way it works.

On the plus side, you get x64 architecture with its attendant boosts to speed, number of registers, physical memory size, etc.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with .NET.  Every application, when built for a 64-bit processor, takes more memory than when built for a 32-bit processor.

If you can think of a way to squeeze 64 bits of information into a 32-bit register, I'm sure we'd all love to hear how.

Answer (score 0):

Just don´t worry about it. Using a x64 system you can install up to 16 exabytes of RAM =)

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in .NET 2.0 [Service Pack 1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945757/en-us).

Comment: Yes - you'd kind of expect the SP1 release note to show up in search results for the original KB number - but it didn't for me (I had to go to the release note directly and then look it up in the list).